# How to catch a Python exception from VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I’m using xlwings and calling python from VBA using the `RunPython` function. However exceptions such as `ValueError`  are not caught by VBA in the standard way, for example:

```
Sub Test()
   On Error Goto PythonError
   RunPython(“…”)
   Exit Sub
PythonEror:
   ‘Do something sensible 
End Sub
```

the error gets propagated to Excel nevertheless. What should I do differently to be able to catch and handle the exception from VBA?

Comment: Presumably RunPython returns an error code given that you've run it as a function rather than a sub.

Comment: @freeflow, unfortunately no, I tested this, the error is propagated all the way out bypassing my try catch in VBA. I don't know what else to do here.